# drive.files.list doesn't doesn't display files which were not previously opened

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm having the following code to query google slides in the google drive (mostly from shared google folders and shared team drive).

The code works well and lists all the slides (in the `data` variable) from both google drive folders as well as google team drive, however in the latter case it only displays items shared with me which I've previously opened (i.e. I went to the team drive website and manually opened the slides shared with me via google team drive).

If I don't open files in the google team drive manually, they won't show up via the `drive.files.list` query at which I can go ahead and first open them after which they will start showing in the query results...

```
let pageToken = null
let params = {
  auth,
  orderBy: 'modifiedTime desc',
  q: `mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.presentation" and trashed = false`,
  pageToken,
  pageSize: 1000,
}

params.includeTeamDriveItems = true
params.supportsTeamDrives = true
params.fields =
    'files(id,name,modifiedTime,createdTime,properties,description,parents,mimeType,teamDriveId)'

const { data } = await this.drive.files.list(params)
```

This seems like a really strange behavior, especially that files which are shared with me via regular google drive shared folder (rather than team drive) are returned in the query correctly regardless of whether they were opened before or not.

Is this some bug with the google drive API?

Comment: Curiously the `files.list` response has a boolean field `viewedByMe`, but this apparently isn't a searchable field (for the "q" parameter).

Comment: Any time you use `files.list`, you need to iterate until the nextPageToken is null|undefined, otherwise you will not see all of the results.